# How to keep Bison state while parsing chunks of different streams?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, multiple-instances, stateful

I have a single Bison parser definition to apply to several streams. Each stream is produced in chunks at certain intervals, thus I would like to save the state of a given parsing instance, in order to switch among different streams, while keeping the state (with their associated stacks) of each of parsing instance.

I know there is the possibility to switch among several buffers from the scanner, but this does not help me with building a different parsing tree for each stream I am analyzing.

Is there any Bison functionality which allows to perform what function `yy_switch_to_buffer()` does in `flex`?

Comment: Be careful when tagging.  The Flex tag is used for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.  Flex-lexer is used for the lexical analyzer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [pure (reentrant) parser interface](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Decl), which allows you to maintain separate parser states. You'll probably also want to use a [reentrant flex lexer](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant.html), so that each parser state has its own lexer state. (You could use a single lexer and switch buffers every time you call it, but the reentrant lexer interface is a lot cleaner, and more general since it preserves all lexer state including, for example, start condition and buffer stacks.)